# Hereditary algebras as quotient algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quivers

This is the first time I post a question on MO, so I'm shy a liite bit. Can you give a "non-trivial" example of a finite dimensional hereditary algebra which is quotient of an infinite dimensional algebra ?
By "non-trivial" I mean not by killing loops in the path algebra of some quiver, for example 
$k[X_1] \times\ldots \times k[X_n]/((X_1)\times\ldots\times (X_n))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use generators and relations, then any algebra is a quotient of an infinite-dimensional algebra, i.e., a quotient of the free associative algebra corresponding to the generators you pick.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the answer !